# Access Denied for sub site (with remove inheritance)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a root site, (root site collection), I created a sub site with break inheritance from root site (remove inheritance). I gave user1 permission to the sub site, but he has no permissions on root site. when he browses to sub site he gets Access Denied. I don't know why. 
I used a module to provision my images and css files on root web which the sub site uses as well (same master page). can it be because of that? how can i fix this problem? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, check the user has permissions to master page, CSS and images. If we didn't had permission on those files,  we always get the AccessDenied.

Comment: And make sure they are checked in, published as major versions and approved.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, it's always better to put your Images, CSS etcs in the Master Page Gallery (_catalogs/masterpage). Even anonymous users have permission to the files stored here so you wont have any permission issues accessing this gallery from a sub site with broken inheritance.

Comment: Hi, I have still same problem. I moved CSS and Javascript files to 14 hive by using Sharepoint mapped folder on Visual Studio and My master page is in _catalogs/masterpage but still I get access denied for sub sites. any idea? thanks.

Comment: AT the risk of reviving a very old question - how do you do this in VS 2012? I'm having no luck finding what the mapped path setup should be to deploy this in a WSP.

Comment: You will have to use a Module to deploy your JS and CSS files. Here is an example in VS 2010 but the process is exactly the same. http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2011/05/15/deploy-custom-cssjs-files-in-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010/